# How to define a flexible 'function expression' in R

Tags: r, function, expression

Is it possible to write a flexible function expression?
I want to use input arguments to control the expression of function.

For example

```
input arg -> function
c(1,1) -> func1 = function(x) x+1
c(1,3,2) -> func2 = function(x) x^2+3*x+2
c(6,8,-1) -> func3 = function(x) 6*x^2+8*x-1
```

Comment: Your last example should be 6x^2 + 8x + 1, I think.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `polynom`

```
library(polynom)
as.polynomial(c(2,3,1))
2 + 3*x + x^2 
as.polynomial(c(6,8,1)
1 + 8*x + 6*x^2
```

**EDIT** you can of course coerce the result to a function using `the generic`as.function.polynomial`. better here you can use ,`as.polylist` to create many polynomials given a list of coefficients lists. For example:

```
lapply(as.polylist(list(c(2,3,1),c(6,8,1),c(6,8,-1))),
       as.function)

[[1]]
function (x) 
{
    w <- 0
    w <- 1 + x * w
    w <- 3 + x * w
    w <- 2 + x * w
    w
}
<environment: 0x00000000113bd778>

[[2]]
function (x) 
{
    w <- 0
    w <- 1 + x * w
    w <- 8 + x * w
    w <- 6 + x * w
    w
}
<environment: 0x0000000011524168>

[[3]]
function (x) 
{
    w <- 0
    w <- -1 + x * w
    w <- 8 + x * w
    w <- 6 + x * w
    w
}
<environment: 0x0000000011527f28>
```

Comment: you should probably mention that `as.function` can be used to convert that to a function

Comment: @eddi thanks. I edit my answer to coerce my result to a function.

Answer (score 2):

```
makepoly <- function(b)
{
    p <- rev(seq_along(b) - 1)
    function(x)
    {
        xp <- outer(x, p, '^')
        rowSums(xp * rep(b, each=length(x)))
    }
}

# x^2 + 2x + 3
f <- makepoly(1:3)
f(0:4)
[1]  3  6 11 18 27
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my take on this task

```
create_poly <- function(coef)
paste(rev(coef),
      paste("x", seq_along(coef) - 1, sep = "^"),
      sep = "*", collapse = " + ")


make_polyfun <- function(input) {
    myfun <- paste("function(x)", create_poly(input))
    eval(parse(text = myfun))
}
```

With the example the OP gave we have :

```
make_polyfun(c(1, 1))
## function(x) 1*x^0 + 1*x^1
## <environment: 0x243a540>

make_polyfun(c(1, 3, 2))
## function(x) 2*x^0 + 3*x^1 + 1*x^2
## <environment: 0x1bd46e0>

make_polyfun(c(6, 8, 1))
## function(x) 1*x^0 + 8*x^1 + 6*x^2
## <environment: 0x22a59c0>
```

Comment: +1; This actually is more responsive to the question since you noticed that the order of hte coefficients was highest to lowest and I did not.

Comment: @DWin Thanks but a this level is not really a big deal just a convention. By the way nice use of `body`

Comment: Thank u dickoa! this is what i want. sorry my question was not clear at 1st. What I need is a flexible 'function expression', which I can use further in other places, not a function.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear how general you want to be from OP. For the particular case of polynomials, you can do:

```
f = function(x, coeffs) {
  sum(outer(x, seq_along(coeffs) - 1, `^`) * coeffs)
}

f(2, c(1,2,3)) # 1 + 2*x + 3*x^2, with x = 2
#[1] 17
```

Answer (score 1):

I read this as the desire to make functions and I think the agstudy/eddi responses would probably do this, but I thought trying it from scratch might be instructive:

```
 poly.maker <- function(coefs) { func <- function(x){} #empty func in x
             body(func) <- parse(text= paste( seq_along(coefs),"*x^",   
                                  (length(coefs)-1):0,collapse="+" ) ) 
             return(func) }
 func2 <- poly.maker(c(1,2,3))  # return a function
 func2(3)  # now test it out
#[1] 18
```

Note I needed to swap the order to agree with the OP request, which I only noticed after getting different results than @dickoa. This seems less clunky:

```
 poly.make2 <- function(coefs) { func <- function(x){} 
        body(func) <- bquote(sum(.(coefs)*x^.( (length(coefs)-1):0 ) ) )
        return(func) }
 func <- poly.make2(c(1,2,5))
 func
#function (x) 
#sum(c(1, 2, 5) * x^c(2L, 1L, 0L))
#<environment: 0x29023d508>
 func(3)
#[1] 20
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner:

```
polymaker2 <- function(coefs)
{
    eval(parse(text=paste0( "function(x) sum(x^(",length(coefs)-1,":0) * ",capture.output(dput(coefs)),")" )))
}
```

Vectorized form:

```
polymaker3 <- function(coefs)
{
    eval(parse(text=paste0( "function(x) colSums(t(outer(x, ",length(coefs)-1,":0, `^`))*",capture.output(dput(coefs)),")" )))
}
```

Comment: Seems rather baroque.

Comment: @DWin According to Merrian-Webster: "baroque: 1. of, relating to, or having the characteristics of a style of artistic expression prevalent especially in the 17th century that is marked generally by use of complex forms, bold ornamentation, and the juxtaposition of contrasting elements often conveying a sense of drama, movement, and tension; 2. characterized by grotesqueness, extravagance, complexity, or flamboyance; 3. irregularly shaped". I like the first meaning :-)

Comment: Particularly noteworthy was:  `..., capture.output( dput( coefs))`

Comment: @DWin, how would you phrase that?

Comment: I tried with this:  bquote(.(coefs)). Returns a numeric vector, but it fails to deliver the correct string for parsing.

Comment: Actually you can use `quote(coefs)` and the code will succeed.

Comment: @DWin, it does succeed, but there is a subtle difference: it creates a reference to the variable `coefs` in the evaluation environment of `polymaker`, such that the closure returned has this environment as its parent. Using the baroque alternative, the closure returned has the global environment as parent, and the evaluation environment is destroyed. This is an interesting feature of R, IMHO.

Comment: Yes. That is the expected behavior of functions in R.